# Are these two promql queries same?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Promql [doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors) says:

> Range vectors select a range of samples back from the current instant
> In this example, we select all the values we have recorded within the last 5 minutes for all time series that have the metric name `http_requests_total` and a job label set to prometheus:
>
> ```
>  http_requests_total{job="prometheus"}[5m]
> ```

Then the doc says following about offset:

> the following expression returns the value of `http_requests_total` 5 minutes in the past relative to the current query evaluation time:
>
> ```
>  http_requests_total offset 5m
> ```

Does that mean this above offset query same as below range query?

```
  http_requests_total[5m]
```

Answer (score 0):

No. This expressions differ quite a lot.

#### Range vector selector

Range vector selector return range (array) of values. In your exact case it would all value of metric scraped within 5 minutes.

Range vector selectors aren't used by themself but as argument to some aggregation function, for example `avg_over_time` or `increase`.

`avg_over_time(http_requests_total[5m])` will calculate average value of metric over last 5 minutes, and `increase(http_requests_total[5m])` how much counter increased over last 5 minutes.

#### Offset

`offset` operator "shifts" timestamp of metric to specified offset value, and saves all other characteristics.

For example `http_requests_total offset 5m` returns value of metrics 5 minutes ago (from specified in request time). And expression like `http_requests_total - http_requests_total offset 5m` will calculate increase of metric over last 5 minutes (similarly to `increase(http_requests_total[5m])` but without benefit of auto handling resets)

Additionally offset operator can also be applied to range vector selectors, so something like `rate(http_requests_total[5m] offset 1h)` is also a valid query.